# T-SQL analytic functions (or analogue) in recursive CTE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a recursive CTE. I use `count (s_) over (partition by c) cc` in column cc in recursive part of that CTE. But I get "1" as result,
but I need to get such result in recursive cte (see Expected result - column cc). Could you give me advise how to get such result in recursive part?

Because I need to use such result in this recursive CTE next.

I try to explain this task. I need to calculate for (column n) in each iteration: 1) calculate count (s_) over (partition by c) as cc 2) calculate min from cc (min of count (s_) over (partition by c)) 3) exclude values from column S with min from cc (min of count (s_) over (partition by c)) before next each iteration and re-calculate items 1) 2) 3)

```
create table cor (nb int, s varchar(10), c varchar(10))

insert into cor values ( 1 , 's1' , 'c1'  )
insert into cor values ( 1, 's2' , 'c1')
insert into cor values ( 1, 's3' , 'c2' ) 
insert into cor values ( 1, 's4' , 'c3' )
insert into cor values ( 1, 's5' , 'c3' )
insert into cor values ( 1, 's6' , 'c4')

create table sr (num int, s varchar(10))


insert into sr values ( 1  , 's1' )
insert into sr values ( 1 , 's2' )
insert into sr values ( 1 , 's3' )
insert into sr values ( 2  , 's1' )
insert into sr values ( 2 , 's2' )
insert into sr values ( 2  , 's6' )
insert into sr values ( 3 , 's1' )
insert into sr values ( 3 , 's3' )
insert into sr values ( 3 , 's4' )
insert into sr values ( 4 , 's1' )
insert into sr values ( 4  , 's3' )
insert into sr values ( 4  , 's4' )
insert into sr values ( 4 , 's6')
with  rec as (


select  1 n, nb, s , c , cast(0 as int) num, cast('' as varchar(50)) s_  , 0 nn, 0 cc  from cor 

union all
select r.*, count (s_) over (partition by c) cc
from 
(
    select t.*, cast(row_number()over(partition by n,s, c order by t.s_ desc ) as int)nn
    from(
        select   1+n n,   cast(sr.num as int) num_, rec.s, rec.c, cast(sr.num as int) num,iif(cast(sr.s as varchar(50))<>rec.s,'1',cast(sr.s as varchar(50)))  s_
                
                    from rec, sr where sr.num=rec.n+1  and sr.num<5
        )t
)r where nn=1
)

select * from rec 
order by n,s
```

I have such result

| n | nЬ | s | c | num | s_ | nn | cc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | s1 | c1 | 2 | s1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | s2 | c1 | 2 | s2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | s3 | c2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | s4 | c3 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | s5 | c3 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Expected result

| n | nЬ | s | c | num | s_ | nn | cc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | s1 | c1 | 2 | s1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | s2 | c1 | 2 | s2 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | s3 | c2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | s4 | c3 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | s5 | c3 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |

Comment: If you just want the top 1 from each group, you can just use top 1 + order by in a subselect instead of trying to describe this in terms of row_number and a later filter to retrieve rn = 1.  I can't grok enough of what you are trying to do here to help for the rest, unfortunately.  If you just want count of each number of a group, using count(*) group by col may be more common?

Comment: Hello,  
Conor Cunningham, I try to explain this task.  
I need to calculate for (column n) in each iteration:
1) calculate count (s_) over (partition by c) as cc
2) calculate min from cc (min of count (s_) over (partition by c)) 
3) exclude values from column S  with min from cc (min of count (s_) over (partition by c)) 
before next each iteration and re-calculate items 1) 2) 3)

Answer (score 2):

`count (s_) over (partition by c) cc` in recursion doesn't see whole output and can't count properly. But you can use it in the final select.

```
with  rec as (
select  1 n, nb, s, c, cast(0 as int) num, cast('' as varchar(50)) s_  , 0 nn from cor 
union all
select r.*
from 
(
    select t.*, cast(row_number()over(partition by n,s, c order by t.s_ desc ) as int)nn
    from(
        select   1+n n,   cast(sr.num as int) num_, rec.s, rec.c, cast(sr.num as int) num,iif(cast(sr.s as varchar(50))<>rec.s,'1',cast(sr.s as varchar(50)))  s_
                
                    from rec, sr where sr.num=rec.n+1  and sr.num<5
        )t
)r where nn=1
)

select rec.*, count (c) over (partition by n,c) cc from rec 
order by n,s
```

[image]

Or you can add one more CTE without recursion but with analytic function.

```
with  rec as (
select  1 n, nb, s, c, cast(0 as int) num, cast('' as varchar(50)) s_  , 0 nn from cor 
union all
select r.*
from 
(
    select t.*, cast(row_number()over(partition by n,s, c order by t.s_ desc ) as int)nn
    from(
        select   1+n n,   cast(sr.num as int) num_, rec.s, rec.c, cast(sr.num as int) num,iif(cast(sr.s as varchar(50))<>rec.s,'1',cast(sr.s as varchar(50)))  s_
                
                    from rec, sr where sr.num=rec.n+1  and sr.num<5
        )t
)r where nn=1
), res as(
select rec.*, count (c) over (partition by n,c) cc from rec 
)

select * from res
order by n,s
```

The result is the same.

Comment: NO, maybe there is some other way to calculate count() in recursion because next I need to use this result  in the next iteration this recursion

Comment: Here it is explained how recursive CTE works with analytical functions: [I. Use analytical functions in a recursive CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql)

If you do not want to use `count` in the final select statement, you may add one more CTE containing `select rec.*, count (c) over (partition by n,c) cc from rec order by n,s` and then select from it.

Comment: it is not clear what you are suggesting, i need to use result of count() in next iteration of recursion. Then i try to use such code, i have a error, see code `union all

select  n, nb, s, c, num, s_, nn, count (s_) over (partition by c) cc from rec r` in my cte

Comment: kir kir, I have added one more variant in my code with two CTEs. So the final select doesn't contain any calculations. Analytic functions don't work in recursive CTE. Even `row_number()` works incorrectly in your code. But it is expected behaviour, according to the link I attached in the previous comment.

Comment: Olesia, i need to calculate count() in cte rec, because i need to use this result (count()) in cte rec in next iteration.  May  be you can to give advise how to realise it (may be there is some analogue). (It so difficult to explaine in english (because you and i from Russia and we both speak in Russian)))))

Comment: kir-kir, There is a Russian version of StackOverFlow. You can ask there if you'd like. But I would suggest to add this next iteration in your question for better understanding your problem and we will try to help.

Comment: I try to explain this task. I need to calculate for (column n) in each iteration: 1) calculate count (s_) over (partition by c) as cc 2) calculate min from cc (min of count (s_) over (partition by c)) 3) exclude values from column S with min from cc (min of count (s_) over (partition by c)) before next each iteration and re-calculate items 1) 2) 3)

Comment: What should be the expacted result for `n = 2`?

Comment: pls, close my question

Comment: As I know, the question cannot be closed here. You can accept the answer and probably others will not answer it again. Or I think you can edit the title of your question and add something like [closed] or whatever.